# Use ktlint to format during maven build

Tags: maven, kotlin, ktlint

I used the following settings for ktlint which allowed auto-formatting for all files during a local maven build but never triggered a pipeline failure if formatting was incorrect:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>com.github.gantsign.maven</groupId>
    <artifactId>ktlint-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.6.1</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
        <id>format-and-check</id>
        <goals>
            <goal>format</goal>
            <goal>check</goal>
        </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

For ktlint to trigger a pipeline failure if formatting is incorrect I changed the settings to

```
<execution>
    <id>verify-code-style</id>
    <phase>validate</phase>
    <goals>
        <goal>check</goal>
    </goals>
</execution>
```

Which does trigger a failure instantly.

But - now I cannot do a local maven build and make use of auto-formatting. Instead it instantly triggers a failure, requiring manual action for example `Needless blank line(s)` in class X on line Y.

I would like to have the best of both worlds - trigger a failure in the pipeline and make use of auto-formatting locally. Is there any way to achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you want differing behaviour locally compared to your CI, I think the simplest solution would to just run the format goal before the build command that you run locally.

So instead of mvn deploy (or package or whatever you run), just run

```
mvn ktlint:format deploy
```